# Por qué mi columna ID que es AutoIncrement no comienza desde 1 al guardar registros?

Tags: java, mysql

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`id_usuario` es **PK**, **NN** y **AI**

Al inicio sí comenzaba desde 1 pero, borre todos los registros y vía mi programa en Java guardé nuevos pero, los registros no comenzaron desde 1, comenzaron desde el último número de los registros que había borrado.

¿Por qué los registros no comienzan desde el número 1?. Comienzan desde el número de los registros que había borrado antes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de dos maneras:

1. Modificar solo el valor de AUTO_INCREMENT

`ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=1`

2. Puedes vaciar la tabla restableciendola:

`TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;`

Comment: vale, elegí esta como solución a mi respuesta ya que estoy haciendo algo para probar localmente y necesito poder volver al ID 1 para seguir probando. No sabía como indicarle a la base de datos que regrese al 1, gracias por la solución. La explicación de las demas respuestas las he entendido perfecto para un caso de un programa de producción.

Answer (score 8):

Esto se debe a que ese campo es AUTO_INCREMENT. Cuando un campo es AUTO_INCREMENT, empiezan a contar desde el número 1 pero sin embargo si borras registros el siguiente AUTO_INCREMENT, aunque lo hayas borrado, será el siguiente al registro que hayas borrado.

Por ejemplo si tienes los registros `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` y borras el registro número `5` el AUTO_INCREMENT empezará en el número `6` para la siguiente inserción.

**Explicación de porqué el campo AUTO_INCREMENT funciona de esa manera:**

He visto que en las demás respuestas te dicen como volver a poner los registros del campo `AUTO_INCREMENT` de nuevo a `1`. Sin embargo, las bases de datos guardan el id del último registro añadido (aunque los borres) debido a que puede generar problemas de seguridad y de inconsistencia de datos.

**No te recomiendo para nada que cambies los ID de un campo `AUTO_INCREMENT`. En caso de que lo hagas, hazlo siempre en un entorno de pruebas y asegurándote de que no puede afectar a tablas relacionadas. Nunca lo ejecutes en un entorno de producción.**

¿Por qué? Muy sencillo. Los campo `AUTO_INCREMENT` normalmente se utilizan para asignar ID's a los elementos de tus tablas, los cuales **SON ÚNICOS**. Imagínate una tabla de usuarios que se registran en tu aplicación con el campo id `AUTO_INCREMENT`, por ejemplo, como un foro tipo `Stackoverflow`.

Ahora imagínate que hay tres usuarios en la base de datos y que el usuario con ID 1 crea tres posts. Cada post va asociado a ese usuario 1, por lo tanto, aparecerá el nombre del creador.

Posteriormente, borras los tres usuarios de la tabla y pones de nuevo el valor del campo `AUTO_INCREMENT` con el valor 1.

Ahora creas un usuario nuevo y, al haber modificado tu campo id AUTO_INCREMENT, este nuevo usuario se le registra en la base de datos con el número 1. Por lo tanto, los tres posts que ha creado el usuario anterior con el ID 1, van a estar relacionados con el nuevo usuario ID 1, lo cual no es correcto.

Por eso, no te recomiendo nunca volver a inicializar el valor de un campo AUTO_INCREMENT a menos de que estés seguro de que no va a afectar al resto de tablas en la base de datos en cuanto a consistencia de datos se refiere (en el ejemplo anterior tendrías una inconsistencia de datos ya que se estarían mostrando datos erróneos para un usuario, al cual le has asignado una ID que ya había sido asignada anteriormente y la cual tenía relación con otras tablas).

Comment: Excelente información, muchas gracias, no sabía nada de eso.

Comment: Bueno, nada de eso pasaría si tiene un foreign ley not null :D

Comment: @PabloContreras Pero en ese caso aunque un usuario se diera de baja realmente no borrarías ese usuario de la base de datos si no que simplemente no le darías acceso a la plataforma.

Answer (score 2):

Internamente el manejador de base de datos va guardando el registro del último Id que se autoincrementó, para iniciar desde 1 nuevamente es con la instrucción

`ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`