# Reiniciar un auto_increment mediante java

Tags: java

Buenas tardes
estoy creando una pagina web con java 
estoy subiendo un archivo de excel a una jsp para guardarlo en MySQL
al momento en que estoy leyendo el archivo en ella lo voy guardando en un ArrayList para guardarlo en MySQL ordenado alfabéticamente, la tabla en MySQL donde va a quedar el archivo guardado tiene una clave primaria compuesta por tres columnas y una es auto_increment, lo que necesito es que al momento de guardarlo en MySQL el auto_incremente se me reinicie por cada  registro ejemplo

```
 1    andrés
 2    andres
 3    andrés
 1    david
 2    david
 1    Fernando
 2    Fernando
 3    Fernando
 4    Fernando
```

subo la parte donde estoy leyendo el excel
soy muy nuevo en esto si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho

```
package models;

import dao.TablaJiraDao;
import dao.TablaNovedadesDao;
import dao.TablaNovedadEmpleadoDao;
import entidades.TablaJira;
import entidades.TablaNovedadEmpleado;
import entidades.TablaNovedades;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadExcel2 {

    public static void leerArchivoExcel2(FileInputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Row fila;
        List<TablaJira> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        TablaJira ji;

        for (int i = 1; i < firstSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {

            fila = firstSheet.getRow(i);

            ji = new TablaJira();

            for (int j = 0; j < fila.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                Cell celda = fila.getCell(j);

                if (j == 0) {

                    if (celda == null || celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                        break;
                    }

                }

                switch (j) {

                    case 0:
                        if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            ji.setProyecto(celda.getStringCellValue());

                        }

                        //   n.setNovedad(celda.getStringCellValue());
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            ji.setTipo(celda.getStringCellValue());
                        }
                        //ne.setFecha_inicio(celda.getStringCellValue());
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            ji.setClave(celda.getStringCellValue());
                        }
                        //ne.setFecha_fin(celda.getStringCellValue());

                        break;

                    case 3:
                        if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            ji.setTitulo(celda.getStringCellValue());
                        }
                        //ne.setAño(celda.getStringCellValue());

                        break;
                    case 4:
                        if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            ji.setNombres(celda.getStringCellValue());

                            // System.out.println(celda.getStringCellValue());
                        }
                        /*           String des = ji.getNombres();

                        List<String> order = new ArrayList<>();
                        order.add(des);
                         Collections.sort(order);
                         order.forEach((item) -> {
                             System.out.println(item);
                });*/

                        //order.forEach((nombre) -> {
                        //  System.out.println(nombre);
                        //});
                        /* String des = "";
                        des = ji.getNombres();
                        order = des.split("");

                         Arrays.sort(order);*/
 /* for (int n = 0; n < order.length; n++) {
                System.out.println(n+ ",");
                }*/
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                            ji.setTiempo_horas((int) celda.getNumericCellValue());
                        }

                        //else if (celda.getCellType()== Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
                        //ne.setHoras(celda.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                }
            }

            //Se guardan los datos por cada fila
            //guardarTablaNovedadEmpleado(ne);
            //guardarTablaNovedades(n);

            if (ji.getNombres() != null) {
                lst.add(ji);

               /*String nombres=ji.getNombres();
                if (nombres!=nombre_ant){
                con=1;

                }else{
                con++;
                   nombre_ant=nombres;
                }*/




            }

        }

        Collections.sort(lst, TablaJira.NameComparator);

//                new Comparator<TablaJira>() {
//            @Override
//            public int compare(TablaJira tb1, TablaJira tb2)
//            {
//                return tb2.getNombres().compareTo(tb1.getNombres());
//            }
//        });
        lst.forEach(ReadExcel2::guardarTblJira);

    }

    private static void guardarTblJira(TablaJira ji) {
        TablaJiraDao dao = new TablaJiraDao();
        dao.insertarTablaJira(ji);

    }
```

Comment: Si escribo "autoincrement" en el buscador de éste mismo sitio me sale [la primera de todas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37145/por-qu%c3%a9-mi-columna-id-que-es-autoincrement-no-comienza-desde-1-al-guardar-regist) la misma pregunta para tu mismo motor de base de datos. Deberías de investigar un poco más tus dudas antes de hacer más preguntas.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías pensar el quitar el `auto_increment` de ese campo. Se supone que el comportamiento debe ser así, que automáticamente se vaya incrementando. Deberías de calcular el valor en lugar de dejarlo automático.