# Error en phpMyAdmin Undefined Index y AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este Error se me presenta al ejecutar, lo mas raro es que registra, pero no el username.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porque no me registra? Les colocare el Codigo de las paginas aqui para que lo visualicen mejor. Por Otra parte. ¿Porque si no hay otro registro aparece el campo iduser que es AI en 6? ¿no debería reiniciarse cuando no hay otros? como puedo hacer eso? que si no hay otro se empiece de 1 otra vez... ? Pensando bien esto, es algo complicado hacer uso del campo autoincremental ya que como se hace cuando un usuario se borra y se pierde la secuencia? se ve feo...  1...2...5 :S

- Form1.html

> ```
>  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
>     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
> ```

```
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Taller Mecanico</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1> Registro de Usuarios</h1>

    <form action="r1usuario.php" method="post">
    Ingrese su USERNAME:
    <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    Ingrese su CONTRASEÑA:
    <input type="password" placeholder="pass" name="password_u" /><br />
    Seleccione Tipo de USUARIO:

    <select name="tipo_u"><br />
    <option value="1">Administrador</option>
    <option value="2">Recepcionista</option>
    <option value="3">Mecanico</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Resgistrar" />
    </form>


    </body>
    </html>
```

- r1usuario.php

<-!-DOCTYPE html>//que problema al poner esto en tipo codigo la pagina lo toma y no lo muestra jaja
 <-html->

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

<title>Registro de Usuario</title>

</head>

<body>
<?php

 $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","taller_bdphp") 
 or die ("Problemas con la conexion ");

 mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios(username,password_u,tipo_u)VALUES ('$_REQUEST[username]',$_REQUEST[password_u],$_REQUEST[tipo_u])") 
 or die ("Problemas en el SELECT" .mysqli_error($conexion)); mysqli_close($conexion); 
 echo ("El USUARIO fue REGISTRADO ");

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la segunda pagina la que llamaste, r1usuario.php quítale la parte que dice: `content="text/html;`. Bórralo y no le pongas nada... ese código infinito que pone Dw puede perjudicar a veces.

Comment: Bro gracias D: ... entonces era eso nada mas... ._. pero ¿que hacia ese codigo que no me dejaba? para que servia ese codigo que borre? y aun no se como hacer con el AI :(

Comment: Buenas, creo que por tu pregunta, hubo algo similar en el caso de AutoIncrement en esta comunidad, te recomiendo ver en la pregunta respondida: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37145/por-qu%c3%a9-mi-columna-id-que-es-autoincrement-no-comienza-desde-1-al-guardar-regist] espero que te haya ayudado con el AI.